# Unable to accept the permission prompt on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to get permissions for `location` and `name` for my app. 
Here is my `index.js` - [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25084001/)

It seems to be stuck in a loop :-
[image]

Here are my intents on API.AI :-
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also post a picture of that intent, and any other intents you might have, with the Events section expanded?

Comment: @Prisoner Edited ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event `actions_intent_PERMISSION` needs to be attached to an Intent that will be called **after** the user authorizes the information to be sent. The handling for it in the webhook needs to read the information given and save it or do something with it immediately.

Your code is looping because the code that is processing the `request_permission` action is, itself, requesting permission:

```
function requestPermission(app){
    const permissions = [
      app.SupportedPermissions.NAME,
      app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION
    ];
    app.askForPermissions('To pick you up', permissions);
}
```

So you will need:

- A new intent
- that has `actions_intent_PERMISSION` set for the event
- that has a new action string associated with it
- and maps to a new function that handles the information that the user has consented to.

Comment: I would just echo @Prisoner's suggestion to use the actions_intent_PERMISSION event in the new API.AI intent you create.

Comment: Thanks @SachitMishra - I've added that bullet to make sure it was clear.

Comment: @Prisoner I am trying the same with dialogflow-fulfillment but I am not getting any prompt asking for permissions.

Comment: @Sachin - Without seeing exactly what you're doing or how, it is difficult to diagnose what you're doing that varies from this answer. Please create a nw question discussing your problem and showing the code you're using.