# API.ai Actions on Google API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field."

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai

I am using python to create webhook for Assistat app. I am able to ask user for location permission, but as soon as user gives consent, I receive following error

```
UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field.".
```

I have checked my webhook server and no request comes to it. This looks like some issue at API.ai side. 
Below is the Debug response from Actions console when using Python client

```
{
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {
    "curlCommand": "curl -v '<URL>'{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"<USED_ID>\",\"locale\":\"en-US\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1504592665563\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\\\"]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.PERMISSION\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"yes\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"PERMISSION\",\"textValue\":\"true\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]},\"device\":{\"location\":{\"coordinates\":{\"latitude\":37.4219806,\"longitude\":-122.0841979}}},\"isInSandbox\":true}'",
    "assistantToAgentJson": {
      "user": {
        "userId": "<USED_ID>",
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "1504592665563",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\"]"
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "VOICE",
              "query": "yes"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "name": "PERMISSION",
              "textValue": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "device": {
        "location": {
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 37.4219806,
            "longitude": -122.0841979
          }
        }
      },
      "isInSandbox": true
    }
  },
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {
    "agentToAssistantJson": {
      "message": "Unexpected apiai response format: Empty speech response",
      "apiResponse": {
        "id": "<ID>",
        "timestamp": "2017-09-05T06:24:41.711Z",
        "lang": "en",
        "result": {},
        "status": {
          "code": 200,
          "errorType": "success"
        },
        "sessionId": "1504592665563"
      }
    }
  },
  "sharedDebugInfo": [
    {
      "name": "GOOGLE_SYSTEM_ACTION",
      "debugInfo": "Your query was handled by Actions on Google."
    },
    {
      "name": "GOOGLE_SYSTEM_ACTION",
      "debugInfo": "Your query was handled by Actions on Google."
    },
    {
      "name": "ResponseValidation",
      "subDebugEntry": [
        {
          "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse",
          "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\"."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Python library [Flask-Assistant](http://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html)

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**
Node JS client works... what is the issue with Python client?

Action Console Debug response

```
{
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {
    "curlCommand": "curl -v '<URL>'{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"<USER_ID>\",\"locale\":\"en-US\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"<ID>\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"_actions_on_google_\\\",\\\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\\\"]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.PERMISSION\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"yes\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"PERMISSION\",\"textValue\":\"true\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"device\":{\"location\":{\"coordinates\":{\"latitude\":37.4219806,\"longitude\":-122.0841979},\"formattedAddress\":\"Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States\",\"zipCode\":\"94043\",\"city\":\"Mountain View\"}},\"isInSandbox\":true}'",
    "assistantToAgentJson": {
      "user": {
        "userId": "<USER_ID>",
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "<ID>",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\"]"
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "VOICE",
              "query": "yes"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "name": "PERMISSION",
              "textValue": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "device": {
        "location": {
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 37.4219806,
            "longitude": -122.0841979
          },
          "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
          "zipCode": "94043",
          "city": "Mountain View"
        }
      },
      "isInSandbox": true
    }
  },
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {
    "agentToAssistantJson": {
      "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\"]",
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "expectedInputs": [
        {
          "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "simpleResponse": {
                    "textToSpeech": "Given permission"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "possibleIntents": [
            {
              "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "responseMetadata": {
        "status": {
          "code": 14
        },
        "queryMatchInfo": {
          "queryMatched": true,
          "intent": "Default Welcome Intent - fallback"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Request from Actions server to my Node JS webhook server

```
{ originalRequest: 
   { source: 'google',
     version: '2',
     data: 
      { isInSandbox: true,
        surface: [Object],
        inputs: [Array],
        user: [Object],
        device: [Object],
        conversation: [Object] } },
  id: '<ID>',
  timestamp: '2017-09-06T05:43:21.342Z',
  lang: 'en',
  result: 
   { source: 'agent',
     resolvedQuery: 'actions_intent_PERMISSION',
     speech: '',
     action: 'DefaultWelcomeIntent.DefaultWelcomeIntent-fallback',
     actionIncomplete: false,
     parameters: {},
     contexts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     metadata: 
      { intentId: '<ID>',
        webhookUsed: 'true',
        webhookForSlotFillingUsed: 'false',
        nluResponseTime: 2,
        intentName: 'Default Welcome Intent - fallback' },
     fulfillment: { speech: 'Given permission', messages: [Array] },
     score: 1 },
  status: { code: 200, errorType: 'success' },
  sessionId: '<SID>' 
  }
```

API.ai Intent settings
[image: Fallback Intent for Welcome Intent] 
[image: Fallback Intent details]

Comment: Can you show the JSON you are responding with in your fulfillment.

Comment: I am using flask assistant library http://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html But for this issue, there is no hit on my server.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Intent in API.AI that you think should be handling the consent from the user?

Comment: I have updated!

Comment: What environment are you using for your node.js server, and what environment are you using for your python server? (Firebase Function? Google's App Engine? Some other server environment? Front-ended by something?)

Comment: These errors are coming on local servers. This library is based on flask and using ngrok exposed to world.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you're not getting any hits on your webhook is that you don't have an intent registered to get the reply.

You can do this by creating an Intent with the Event set to `actions_intent_PERMISSION`.

See also the following answers on SO:

- [Unable to accept the permission prompt on Actions on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089687/unable-to-accept-the-permission-prompt-on-actions-on-google/45090178#45090178)
- [Permission response not handled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661883/permission-response-not-handled-correctly/45694477#45694477)

Comment: It's working using node. But with python I am getting this error.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate this info, along with the screen shot of the intent you think is handling it. Since node does handle it, can you also provide the JSON that node is getting when it works?

Comment: did you find the issue?