# API.ai Actions on Google - Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field."

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai

This error is similar to what I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048317/api-ai-actions-on-google-api-version-2-failed-to-parse-json-response-string-wit), but this time it's with NodeJs client. 
I am trying to find directions to a location. As soon as the intent is triggered on my webhook, I am calculating the directions using GoogleMapAPI. But before it can finish and send a response, I receive the error on my Actions Console.
 I checked total response time and it is less than 2 seconds which is less than 5 seconds timeout by Google.
Where I am wrong???

My API.ai Intent 
[image]
[image]

Using express.js with Action-on-Google Node Client

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const intentHandler = require('./intent_handler')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const ApiAiAssistant = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiAssistant;

// Create functions to handle requests here
....
....
const DIRECTION_INTENT = 'action_direction';

function MyAssistant(req, res) {
    const assistant = new ApiAiAssistant({request: req, response: res});
    assistant.handleRequest(responseHandler(assistant));
}


function responseHandler (assistant) {
    // intent contains the name of the intent you defined in the Actions area of API.AI
    let intent = assistant.getIntent();
    switch (intent) {
        case WELCOME_INTENT:
            ...
            break;
        case WELCOME_FALLBACK_PERMISSION_INTENT:
            ...
            break;
        case DIRECTION_INTENT:
            console.log(">>>>>>>DIRECTION_INTENT<<<<<<<");
            intentHandler.directionIntent(assistant);
            break;
    }
}
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   MyAssistant(req, res);
});
app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('app listening on port 8080!')
});
```

Handler Code

```
'use strict';
const speech = require("./speech_template");

const direction = require("./directionModule");

const intent_handler = {

    'welcomeIntent': function (assistant) {
        .....
    },

    'welcomeFallbackPermissionIntent': function (assistant) {
        .....

    },

    'directionIntent':function (assistant) {
        console.log('direction intent');
        direction.getDirectionWithSavedAddress(function (response) {
            assistant.ask(response);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = intent_handler;
```

Direction Extraction --- ERROR comes on Action Console before this get finished

```
'use strict';

const striptags = require('striptags');
const speech = require("./speech_template");

let googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: global.GOOGLE_DIRECTION_KEY
});

const directionModule = {
    'getDirectionWithSavedAddress': function (eventCallback) {
        let myAdd = <From Saved Data>;
        if (myAdd === undefined) {
            console.log("error......");
        }
        let destination = <From Saved Data>;
        this.getDirectionWithAddress(myAdd, destination, function (dir) {
            ....
            if(SUCCESS){
                eventCallback(`<speak> ${steps} </speak>`);
            }else{
                eventCallback(`<speak> ${speech.ERROR_DIRECTIONS} </speak>`);
            }
        });
    },
    'getDirectionWithAddress': function (add1, add2, eventCallback) {
        let dir = {};
        googleMapsClient.directions({
            origin: add1,
            destination: add2,
            mode: "driving",
            departure_time: "now"
        }, function (err, response) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(response.json.routes[0]);
                ....
                ....
                ....
            } else {
                console.log(`Error --> ${err.toString()}`);
                ....
            }
            eventCallback(dir);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = directionModule;
```

**UPDATE**
I am running the code locally via WebStorm and exposing webhook via port forwarding using ngrok.

**Update2**
BAD REQUEST 400

[image]

```
{
    "originalRequest": {
        "source": "google",
        "version": "2",
        "data": {
            "isInSandbox": true,
            "surface": {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "rawInputs": [
                        {
                            "query": "get me there",
                            "inputType": "VOICE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "rawText": "get me there",
                            "textValue": "get me there",
                            "name": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
                }
            ],
            "user": {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "userId": "<uID>"
            },
            "device": {},
            "conversation": {
                "conversationId": "<cID>",
                "type": "ACTIVE",
                "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\"]"
            }
        }
    },
    "id": "<ID>",
    "timestamp": "2017-09-12T17:08:10.321Z",
    "lang": "en",
    "result": {
        "source": "agent",
        "resolvedQuery": "get me there",
        "speech": "",
        "action": "action_direction",
        "actionIncomplete": false,
        "parameters": {},
        "contexts": [
            {
                "name": "_actions_on_google_",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 99
            },
            {
                "name": "google_assistant_input_type_voice",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "actions_capability_audio_output",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "defaultwelcomeintent-followup",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 4
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "intentId": "<iID>",
            "webhookUsed": "true",
            "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
            "nluResponseTime": 15,
            "intentName": "DirectionIntent"
        },
        "fulfillment": {
            "speech": "",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": 0,
                    "speech": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "score": 1
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "errorType": "success"
    },
    "sessionId": "<sID>"
}
```

This looks like before my callback is finished, my webhook is sending empty response to Google Actions.
**Why is this happening and How to resolve it?????**

Comment: Since you are using ngrok, can you also post the HTTP **response** that ngrok records? You should be able to go to ngrok's console URL to view this.

Comment: Updated... there is 400 error!!

Comment: my webhook response is firing even before callback completes... why???

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in how your `directionIntent()` function calls, and handles the result of, your `getDirectionWithSavedAddress()` function. It expects `getDirectionWithSavedAddress()` *returns* a function, when it does not. Instead, `getDirectionWithSavedAddress()` expects to send its results to a *callback*.

So after it makes its call to `getDirectionWithAddress()`, the function ends, returning nothing. This "nothing" is sent to `assistant.ask()`, which returns that to Google's server. This is an invalid response, so you're getting the error.

Fixing this should be straightforward. You need to call `getDirectionWithSavedAddress()` with a callback function. Inside this function you should call `assistant.ask()` with the value sent to the callback.

So `directionIntent()` might look something like

```
    'directionIntent':function (assistant) {
      console.log('direction intent');
      direction.getDirectionWithSavedAddress( function( msg ){
        assistant.ask( msg );
      } );
    }
```

**Updated**

This line makes no sense:

```
assistant.handleRequest(responseHandler(assistant));
```

The `assistant.handleRequest()` function is supposed to be passed a Map of Intent names to functions to call to handle the event. You're doing this manually in the `responseHandler()` function and you're not returning a Map. Since you're not returning a Map, it fails when trying to do the `handleRequest()` and generates the error "Action Error: Request handler can NOT be empty".

You can fix this by just calling `responseHandler(assistant)` and not dealing with `handleRequest()` at all. Or you can create the map that `handleRequest()` is expecting and get rid of `responseHandler()` completely.

Comment: sorry I missed it while editing... I am returning it via a callback only

Comment: aaahhhh..... I switched from map to manual yesterday and and uncommented this line... Thanks a ton !!

Could you look into my earlier post as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048317/api-ai-actions-on-google-api-version-2-failed-to-parse-json-response-string-wit

Comment: that one is tougher to figure out, but its in my queue to take a closer look. any additional info you can provide there is, of course, helpful.